# ggplot2 avoid boxes around legend symbols

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the example plot below.  I'd like to make the little boxes around each of the symbols in the legend go away.  How an I do this?

```
 ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, shape=factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: You may also go to http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Legends%20(ggplot2)/ to see a list of options to modify legends.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
 + opts(legend.key = theme_blank())
```

You can see lots of examples of all sorts of this stuff in `?opts`. I couldn't remember off the top of my head which one it was, so I just tried a few until I got it right.

**Note**: Since version 0.9.2 `opts` has been [replaced](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`:

```
+ theme(legend.key = element_blank())
```