# remove specific legend borders

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to modify the legend to a map by removing the borders around particular cells within the legend.

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
ggplot() + 
  stat_density2d(data = carto@data,
                 aes(x=field_2,y=field_1),
                 geom="polygon",
                 alpha = .37,
                 fill = "#e29206") +
  geom_point(data = Schools@data[Schools@data$sch_type == "Charter" | Schools@data$sch_type == "District", ],
             aes(x = x, y = y, color = sch_type, shape = grade_cat),
             size = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#e0100d", "#4753ff")) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill = "white"))) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank()) +
  coord_map()
```

which produces the following image:

[image]

I would like to remove the blue and red borders on the top two legend cells. If I add `color` to the `override.aes()` arguments within `guides()` it changes the borders, but also makes the charter and district colors the same. Is there a different argument I could use in the place of `color`?

I looked at these two questions (among various sources) before posting:

[Different legend-keys inside same legend in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311335/different-legend-keys-inside-same-legend-in-ggplot2)

[ggplot2 avoid boxes around legend symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270001/ggplot2-avoid-boxes-around-legend-symbols)

Comment: Try removing the lines via `linetype = 0` in the `override.aes` list.

Comment: that worked thanks