# ggplot2 remove legend.key box after combining multiple geom layers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am quite new to ggplot2 and it's been challenging to reproduce a similar chart in Excel. I almost got it to work, but now I need to figure out a way to make the geom_point/line's legend key (3rd item in the legend) to not show the box around it.

Note: I know there are [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270001/ggplot2-avoid-boxes-around-legend-symbols) to similar problem by using `+ theme(legend.key = element_blank())`, but it has no effect on the legend. I suspect it has something to do with the `scale_*_manual` in the code. Any other solutions would be truly appreciated!

```
test <- data.frame(
  group      = 1:5,
  cnt        = rep(600, 5),
  pct_cnt    = rep(0.2, 5),
  prem       = c(12000000, 9800000, 8700000, 11000000, 3500000),
  pct_prem   = c(0.266666667, 0.217777778, 0.193333333, 0.244444444, 
                 0.077777778),
  relativity = c(1.5, 1.2, 1, 0.8, 0.4)
)

theme_set(theme_minimal())
normalizer <- round(max(test$relativity) / max(test$pct_prem), 0)

ggplot(test, aes(x = group)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = pct_prem, fill = 'prem', color = 'prem'), stat = 'identity', position = position_nudge(x = -0.1), width = 0.2) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = pct_cnt, fill = 'cnt', color = 'cnt'), stat = 'identity', position = position_nudge(x = 0.1), width = 0.2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = relativity / normalizer, color = 'rel', fill = 'rel'), size = 5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = relativity / normalizer, color = 'rel'), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(name = 'metric', values = c('prem' = NA, 'cnt' = NA, 'rel' = 'skyblue'),
                     labels = c('prem' = '%Prem', 'cnt' = '%Count', 'rel' = 'LRR')) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = 'metric', values = c('prem' = 'orange', 'cnt' = 'dark green', 'rel' = NA),
                    labels = c('prem' = '%Prem', 'cnt' = '%Count', 'rel' = 'LRR')) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.4), sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*normalizer, breaks = seq(0, 0.4, 0.1) * normalizer, name = 'relativity'))
```

[image: ggplot2 version]
[image: Excel chart]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a method using just `ggplot`, since the color of the box and the color of your legend key itself change simultaneously when using the common `override.aes` fix. Going into the gtable, you could do it this way (after assigning your plot to `p`):

```
library(grid)
grb <- ggplotGrob(p)
#get the index of the legend-grob and store grob as leg
leg_index <- grep("guide-box", sapply(grb$grobs, function(x) x$name))
leg <- grb$grobs[[leg_index]]
```

Then, you want to look in the legend's `gtable`. The key bg to be changed is the last one, so check at the bottom for `rect` backgrounds. I.e., here

```
13 13 (6-6,2-2) key-5-1-bg        zeroGrob[legend.key..zeroGrob.3081]
14 14 (6-6,2-2)  key-5-1-1                       rect[GRID.rect.3082]
15 15 (6-6,2-2)  key-5-1-2                       rect[GRID.rect.3083]
16 16 (6-6,2-2)  key-5-1-3                   points[GRID.points.3084]
17 17 (6-6,2-2)  key-5-1-4               segments[GRID.segments.3085]
```

Indices 14 and 15 are the ones belonging to the last key. To make sure the bg is removed, just change the graphic parameters of both of them. Then replace the old legend with your changed one.

```
leg$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[14]]$gp$col <- "white"
leg$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[15]]$gp$col <- "white"
grb$grobs[[leg_index]] <- leg


grid.newpage()
grid.draw(grb)
```

[image]

Comment: This is really nice! Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To move a legend on the bottom of the graph you add "bottom" to legend.position like this....

```
 theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

here is your original code adjusted..

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = group)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = pct_prem, fill = 'prem', color = 'prem'), stat = 'identity', position = position_nudge(x = -0.1), width = 0.2, alpha = 1) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = pct_cnt, fill = 'cnt', color = 'cnt'), stat = 'identity', position = position_nudge(x = 0.1), width = 0.2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = relativity / normalizer, color = 'rel', fill = 'rel'), size = 5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = relativity / normalizer, color = 'rel'), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(name = 'metric', values = c('prem' = NA, 'cnt' = NA, 'rel' = 'skyblue'),
                     labels = c('prem' = '%Prem', 'cnt' = '%Count', 'rel' = 'LRR')) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = 'metric', values = c('prem' = 'orange', 'cnt' = 'dark green', 'rel' = NA),
                    labels = c('prem' = '%Prem', 'cnt' = '%Count', 'rel' = 'LRR')) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.4) , sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*normalizer, breaks = seq(0, 0.4, 0.1) * normalizer, name = 'relativity'))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

For further adjustments that can be made look up theme (tons of options)

```
?theme
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear. I wanted to make the 3rd item in the legend key (LRR) to have no box around it. I have tried `legend.key = element_blank())` but it wasn't working.

Comment: oh, your looking to have the box around the LRR removed?